# How is the execution order of processes determined for fields like ExecStartPre being specified in original and overriden systemd service files?

Tags: systemd

I want to override a *systemd* service file to add a process started by *ExecStartPre*. The original service already starts two processes with *ExecStartPre*. Is my added process started before or after the two processes already specified in the original service description?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Building a minimal example for *ExecStartPre* showed that the processes added by overriding are executed after the processes specified in the original service file.

(tested version was systemd 236)